# preg_split without replacing?

Tags: php, preg-split

Trying to split a string, but I don't want to "remove" what I'm searching for...

The string Looks like this:

MDVB, 94010, (555) 555-5555, KHII, 94015, (555) 555-5555, POONHY, 94010, (555) 555-5555,

I want to split the string after the phone number, but I don't want to remove the number...

Right now, I have this:

```
preg_split("/\(?  (\d{3})?  \)?  (?(1)  [\-\s] ) \d{3}-\d{4}/x", $string)
```

But that outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MDVB, 94010, 
    [1] => KHII, 94015, 
    [2] => POONHY, 94010, 
)
```

I thought preg_split was the thing to use... Is there something else I should be using?

Comment: Looking at your string you could probably use explode(',', $string);

Comment: No, it's actually a full address line, but as the data contains home addresses, social security numbers, etc., I didn't want to post the full thing, so simplified the data... The string looks more like name,address,city,state,zip,phone,fax,ssn

Answer (score 2):

You should use preg_match_all() to extract portions of your string.

```
<?php
$string = "MDVB, 94010, (555) 555-5555, KHII, 94015, (555) 555-5555, POONHY, 94010, (555) 555-5555,";

$res = preg_match_all("/([A-Z]+,\s+\d+,\s+\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})/",$string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => MDVB, 94010, (555) 555-5555
            [1] => KHII, 94015, (555) 555-5555
            [2] => POONHY, 94010, (555) 555-5555
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => MDVB, 94010, (555) 555-5555
            [1] => KHII, 94015, (555) 555-5555
            [2] => POONHY, 94010, (555) 555-5555
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` option which will cause the parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern to be captured and returned as well.

```
$parts = preg_split("/\(?  (\d{3})?  \)?  (?(1)  [\-\s] ) \d{3}-\d{4}/x",
                    $string,
                    null,
                    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Resulting array:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "MDVB, 94010, "
  [1]=>
  string(3) "555"
  [2]=>
  string(15) ", KHII, 94015, "
  [3]=>
  string(3) "555"
  [4]=>
  string(17) ", POONHY, 94010, "
  [5]=>
  string(3) "555"
  [6]=>
  string(1) ","
}
```

I believe this is the behavior you were looking for.

Comment: No, I'm looking for [0] => MDVB, 94010, (555) 555-5555 [1] KHII, 94015, (555) 555-5555 [3] => POONHY, 94010, (555) 555-5555

Comment: Part of the regex I copied didn't have the phone number in a capture group `( )` so it isn't being captured.  Add the full phone to a capture and it will be part of the array returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use preg_match_all like this:

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?(?:\(? (?:\d{3})? \)? [\-\s] )? \d{3}-\d{4})[^,]*(?:,|$)\s*/x",
               $string, $arr );
print_r($arr[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => MDVB, 94010, (555) 555-5555
    [1] => KHII, 94015, (555) 555-5555
    [2] => POONHY, 94010, (555) 555-5555
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "MDVB, 94010, (555) 555-5555, KHII, 94015, (555) 555-5555, POONHY, 94010, (555) 555-5555,";
preg_match_all("/[A-Za-z]+, \d+, \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

results:

```
var_dump($matches);

array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'MDVB, 94010, (555) 555-5555',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'KHII, 94015, (555) 555-5555',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'POONHY, 94010, (555) 555-5555',
  ),
)
```